# length of string changes and the int which save the length not changing

Tags: java, string

i have a question here:

```
String s1="9578";
String s2="434";        
int len1=s1.length();
int len2=s2.length();
System.out.println(len1);
System.out.println(len2);
String temp;
temp=s1;
s1=s2;
s2=temp; 
System.out.println("after swaping: ");
System.out.println(len1);
System.out.println(len2);
```

The print out will be:

```
4
3
after swaping: 
4
3
```

The values of `len1` and `len2` are not changing. `len1` should point to the `s1` and `len2` should point to `s2`. Why they are not changing?

Comment: Because you already stored the value returned by length in the both variables. This is not Excel!

Comment: Just because you swapped the Strings, but didn't swap the ints or recheck the length of the strings.

Comment: I see how you might think that it should update, but len1 and len2 are simply stored values, not pointers to some memory location that keeps track of the length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you've assigned a value to an `int` (or any other primitive datatype, for that matter), it "forgets" where it came from. Once the value is assigned, it quits being "the length of s1", and is simply 4. No more, and no less.

If you want to continuously reference the length of `s1`, just keep calling `s1.length()` whenever you need it instead of storing it in another variable.

Answer (score 1):

The values of `len1` and `len2` are being evaluated *before* the change is made. Therefore, its values won't change.

Those variables are not related with `s1` nor `s2`, so they don't "update" automatically if `s1` or `s2` change.

In the line

```
int len1 = s1.length();
```

you may think that `len1` is related with `s1`, but it's **wrong**. First, `s1.length()` is evaluated, let's say it evaluates to `4`. Then the value `4` will be assigned to `len1`. In conclusion they are not related.

Answer (score 1):

If it was me, I wouldn't use the `len1` and `len2` variables at all (unless there is another purpose for them other than printing).  This would solve the problem that others have stated of your variables being evaluated before the function calls.  I would do something like this:

```
    String s1="9578";
    String s2="434";        
    System.out.println(s1.length());
    System.out.println(s2.length());
    String temp;
    temp=s1;
    s1=s2;
    s2=temp; 
    System.out.println("after swaping: ");
    System.out.println(s1.length());
    System.out.println(s2.length());
```

I don't know too much Java, but that should solve your problem.

Comment: If you don't know too much Java, here's lesson #1: semicolons go after statements, not in the middle of a method call.  Other than that, great point.

Comment: @ajb WOOPS, sorry, I just copied and pasted (which is really bad programming on my part) and didn't catch those semi-colons.  Fixed the problem and thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

The len1 variable is only calculated when you execute the

```
len1=s1.length();
```

statement.  When you do

```
System.out.println(len1);
```

you're not recalculating the length of the string, you're merely re-printing the old length.  This should yield the desired result.

```
System.out.println("after swaping: ");
len1=s1.length();
len2=s2.length();        
System.out.println(len1);
System.out.println(len2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - Your logic is correct , but you have missed the assignment.

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          String s1="9578";
            String s2="434";        
            int len1=s1.length();
            int len2=s2.length();
            System.out.println(len1);
            System.out.println(len2);
            String temp;
            temp=s1;
            s1=s2;
            s2=temp; 


    len1=s1.length();
    len2=s2.length();

            System.out.println("after swaping: ");
            System.out.println(len1);
            System.out.println(len2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

its because you have already stored the values of your string lengths

```
String s1="9578";
String s2="434";        
int len1=s1.length();
int len2=s2.length();
```

which is 4 and 3, so whenever you will call len1 and len2 it will show the values it is initialized by because you are not updating them after swapping. i hope this clears your doubt :)